# Is it possible to trim wav(GSM) files using NAudio

Tags: c#, naudio

I already trim pcm wav files using NAudio.But cant trim wav gsm using that code.Please help to for that..I need to split wav GSM format using NAudio.

### Code is Below

```
private static void TrimWavFile(WaveFileReader reader, WaveFileWriter writer, int startPosition, int endPosition)
{
    reader.Position = startPosition;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    while (reader.Position < endPosition)
    {
        int segment = (int)(endPosition - reader.Position);
        if (segment > 0)
        {
            int bytesToRead = Math.Min(segment, buffer.Length);
            int bytesRead = reader.Read(buffer, 0, bytesToRead);
            if (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                writer.WriteData(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use this technique to trim GSM but you must make sure that start and end position are exact multiples of the `BlockAlign` of the `WaveFormat`.